# 18.04 How to Restore Default Icon for Removable Drive

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

I did something stupid and unnecessary today. I changed the icon for a removable drive--and regret it.

How do I restore the original or default icon? I have tried to find the original in /usr/shared/icons but have not been able to. I opened Tweaks and tried to change from theme to theme, with reboots in between, but that did not fix it.

Right now one of my removable drives is the correct icon and the other one isn't. How can I fix this? Thanks!

[Screenshot of my Desktpop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1UuV.jpg)

Edit:  I wish I had found a way to REVERT back to the original icon--that was the goal.  However I at least found out WHAT the original icon was and was able to select it and thereby get the original icon back.

The original icon for a USB Externally Mounted Hard Drive is:  /usr/share/icons/Humanity/devices/48/drive-harddisk-usb.svg

I am adding this in case anyone needs the same help in the future.

Comment: screenshot please.

Comment: Your wish is my command :)

Comment: In the file manager, there is an easily overlooked "Revert" button in the "Select Custom Icon" dialog for regular files or filders. This returns a changed icon to default. I don't know if that works for removable drives also (and I do not know how you changed these icons).

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  But the Revert button does not do anything in my case unfortunately :(  Thanks--it certainly seemed like that was the answer, or SHOULD be the answer ;)

Comment: FYI, I changed the icon by right-clicking the icon for the removable drive, clicking on Properties, clicking on the icon in the Properties window, and selecting an icon from one of the folders in /usr/shared/icons folder.  ...AND that was definitely a mistake :(